# CIrcle CI 2.0 codecov: command not found

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0, codecov

I am migrating project to Circle CI 2.0.

Here is my **config.yml** file.

```
version: 2

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/android:api-26-alpha
      - image: circleci/python:3.6.1
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: pre-dependencies
          command: pip install --user codecov
      - run: sdkmanager --licenses
      - run:
          name: override-test
          command: ./gradlew --info install test coverage
      - run:
          name: post-test
          command: codecov
```

The Circle CI build is failing because of the last step showing this error.

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
npm install codecov
/bin/bash: npm: command not found
Exited with code 127
```

The step pre-dependencies downloaded codecov libraries, here is the output of this step:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
pip install --user codecov
Collecting codecov
  Downloading codecov-2.0.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests>=2.7.9 (from codecov)
  Downloading requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (88kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 3.5MB/s 
Collecting coverage (from codecov)
  Downloading coverage-4.5.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (199kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 204kB 3.2MB/s 
Collecting urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 (from requests>=2.7.9->codecov)
  Downloading urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl (132kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 3.4MB/s 
Collecting idna<2.7,>=2.5 (from requests>=2.7.9->codecov)
  Downloading idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 2.7MB/s 
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests>=2.7.9->codecov)
  Downloading chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 143kB 3.4MB/s 
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests>=2.7.9->codecov)
  Downloading certifi-2018.1.18-py2.py3-none-any.whl (151kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 153kB 3.3MB/s 
Installing collected packages: urllib3, idna, chardet, certifi, requests, coverage, codecov
Successfully installed certifi-2018.1.18 chardet-3.0.4 codecov-2.0.15 coverage-4.5.1 idna-2.6 requests-2.18.4 urllib3-1.22
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*disclaimer: Developer Evangelist at CircleCI*

Change the line: `pip install --user codecov` to `sudo pip install codecov`.

The second command installs Codecov with the correct permissions to be used as a shell command.